# Get Performance Counter in Driver

Tags: windows, driver

I can get time in Ring3 by QueryPerformanceCounter(). In windows driver, I want to get Performance Counter. Is there function like QueryPerformanceCounter()?

Comment: KeQueryPerformanceCounter ?

Comment: Thank Alex, you are right. I get it. More information can see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553053(v=vs.85).aspx